# settowidth is inaccurate with tabular environments

Tags: tables

I have a need to automatically set the width of a tabular environment; for certain reasons the `tabularc/x/y` environment won't work quite right.  I have some code that uses `\settowidth` to measure the width of a sample table; I can then build on that to do the calculation I need.  Unfortunately, though, `\settowidth` doesn't seem to produce consistent results.  In my (large and complex) real document, the calculated width omits the width of the rules at the left and right sides of the tables; this eventually produces an overfull hbox.

The following short file demonstrates the problem. If you format the file (with either latex or pdflatex) and view a magnified result, you'll see that the horizontal rule isn't quite as wide as the table, while the vertical rule exactly matches the height. I've included a screenshot of the lower-left corner as an example of how it looks:

Surely this isn't a bug? Yet there's clearly more ink that `\settowidth` claims...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tabletest}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|r|}
        \hline
        Some & data\\
        \hline
        Some more & stuff\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}

\newlength{\tabledepth}
\newlength{\tableheight}
\newlength{\tablewidth}
\settodepth{\tabledepth}{\tabletest}
\settoheight{\tableheight}{\tabletest}
\settowidth{\tablewidth}{\tabletest}

\addtolength{\tableheight}{\tabledepth}

\noindent\rule{4pt}{\tableheight}\hspace*{2pt}\tabletest
\\[-6pt]
\noindent\hspace*{6pt}\rule{\tablewidth}{4pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just load the `array` package, what do you observe?

Comment: The vertical rules take up zero width. This may cause them to bump into text, but will *not* cause overfull  hbox errors! (Funny, I recalled that tabular `\hline`s also took up zero height.) By the way, there is `\settototalheight` so you don't need to add depth plus height.

Answer (score 1):

The array package implements tabular rules differently than TeX, it takes care of horizontal/vertical rule width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tabletest}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|r|}
        \hline
        Some & data\\
        \hline
        Some more & stuff\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}

\newlength{\tabledepth}
\newlength{\tableheight}
\newlength{\tablewidth}
\settodepth{\tabledepth}{\tabletest}
\settoheight{\tableheight}{\tabletest}
\settowidth{\tablewidth}{\tabletest}

\addtolength{\tableheight}{\tabledepth}

\noindent\rule{4pt}{\tableheight}\hspace*{2pt}\tabletest
\\[-6pt]
\noindent\hspace*{6pt}\rule{\tablewidth}{4pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the \settotalheight tip; I had somehow missed its existence.

I had tried the array package for other reasons, but unfortunately it completely breaks my document because I do quite a bit of dynamically constructing arguments to the tabular environment.

I guess I could (a) look into the overfull hboxes more carefully, if the rules are supposed to take zero width, and (b) try harder with the array environment and lots of \expandafter.  Or I could just ignore the overfull hbox messages, which would annoy me but is actually fairly harmless in the real world.